# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:image/image.dart'

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I updated my flutter today and I had a lot of problems with the image package.

Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:image/image.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.darturi_does_not_exist

Comment: did you solved?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have this is pubspec.yaml,

*note remember to have every space in this file aligned

```
dependencies:
  image: ^2.1.14
```

Save that file, if you're running VS Code, it will run the command `pub get` for you automatically, if you're running Android Studio, click on Get Dependencies on the top of the screen after saving the file, otherwise you can do it manually via the terminal with the command `pub get`
then try again

```
import 'package:image/image.dart';
```